# How to create tables with SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create 3 tables with SQLAlchemy declaratively as outlined here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/. However when I run my database.py module the tables never actually get created. Can anyone point me in the right directino as to what I am doing wrong?

```
# database.py
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'), echo=True, 
convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                    autoflush=True,
                                     bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()here
```

Inside of models.py is where I define my models to create the tables. When I run database.py the output I get is

```
$ python database.py
2018-12-05 16:26:37,551 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select version()
2018-12-05 16:26:37,552 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-12-05 16:26:38,072 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select 
current_schema()
2018-12-05 16:26:38,072 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-12-05 16:26:38,597 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test 
plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-12-05 16:26:38,597 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-12-05 16:26:38,863 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test 
unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-12-05 16:26:38,863 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-12-05 16:26:39,383 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show 
standard_conforming_strings
2018-12-05 16:26:39,383 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
```

As you can see no actual SQL commands are being issued to create the tables and I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong. Does anyone have any ideas as to why the tables aren't being created?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your application using `flask run` on the command line, the `__name__ == '__main__'` is False. Therefore, remove this if statement, and your db should be inited.

Also, you can try `from models import Base` instead of just `import models`.